# Will Trim still work if creating a spanned volume of two disks (NOT AS RAID)

Tags: windows-7, ssd, dynamic-disk

Scenario: Just bough a 40 gig SSD, don't want to reinstall OS

Proposed solution: Convert existing HDD and new SSD to a spanned dynamic disk volume, having the SSD being the first part of said volume, then defrag to move system files into the 40 gig space

Problems: Will Trim function in this scenario? What about scheduled defragging, can that be exclusively set to defrag only the HDD part of the spanned volume?

Answer (score 1):

This wont work for multiple reasons.  Drives being added as spanned volumes go at the existing volume and have to be blank.  Since you are adding the SSD, it goes at the end and no data would be written till the first disk was full.

Answer (score 0):

That's a ridiculously overcomplicated idea.

Instead, use [Macrium Reflect Free](http://www.macrium.com/reflectfree.asp) to image your existing HD to a backup file, then Restore that file to your new SSD.  Be Certain to use the Partition Properties button to set the Alignment to Vista/7/1MB when you do the Restore, for maximum SSD performance and lifespan.  Read the Macrium Help file if you have trouble finding the Partition Properties (it becomes enabled when you drag the partition from the backup to the SSD).

Answer (score 0):

From what I've read, if you don't mind reformatting (from an image if, you want), you can absolutely create a spanned volume starting with a SSD followed by a HD. **However**, there is no guarantee the filesystem will put the Windows system files on the SSD. It might just go round-robin. If you're looking to speed disk access times, adding RAM to be used for file cache might be more useful; just go get a cup of coffee when cold booting.