# How does TRIM work on Windows when a spanned volume is created with both HDD & SSD?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, trim

This question is similar to these two: [Does Windows 7 support TRIM for Spanned Dynamic Disks?](https://superuser.com/q/520231/109803) and [Will Trim still work if creating a spanned volume of two disks (NOT AS RAID)](https://superuser.com/q/257385/109803) But they are for an much older version of windows and my situation is slightly different.

#### Background

I am creating a very large network drive using windows 10 that will be the merge of two ssds and two hdds.

#### Question

Does windows 10 support the TRIM management of the blocks on the spanned volume that happen to reside on the SSD?

Comment: I very much doubt Microsoft is still working on improving Dynamic Disks. It’s a legacy technology. Storage Spaces largely supersedes Dynamic Disks.

Comment: Why would you even have a striped drive across an HDD and SSD?

Comment: @Seth It’s a type of [concatenation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-RAID_drive_architectures#Concatenation_.28SPAN.2C_BIG.29). No striping or RAID involved.

Comment: What does it matter? You won't be able to tell where your data lands from what I know. You're mixing (in comparison) insanely fast drives with mediocre drives. Your access time is going to be vastly affected depending on where data is written to. Sure for just "I need storage" that is a valid approach but I have to wonder why you'd not just get another bunch of HDDs or at least create two volumes so you know which one is the "fast" one.

Comment: Yeah that would be ideal. I'm in this situation though b/c I'm just a college student with no budget scraping together what I can find. My laptop doesn't have enough space to store my big-data sets. So I need a large network folder running of a junk pc to serve as my data lake. Unless you have a better idea. This is all I can think of at the moment.